# Error Message when sqooping oracle table into hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, kerberos, sqoop

I was looking to find out how I can fix the following error message that I keep getting when I am sqooping a data table into oracle. I was able to sqoop another table this morning but every attempt after that has failed. The following is the error within the log file:

```
Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
```

I am not sure why I keep getting this error message as without the Kerberos Ticket I am unable to login to Putty in order to run the script to sqoop the table and hence I am confused as to a) why I am getting this error b)what I can do to fix it.

Would appreciate it if somebody could advise where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Part of the Error Message from Log File:

```
17/01/05 15:08:52 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.7.1
17/01/05 15:08:52 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/01/05 15:08:52 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
17/01/05 15:08:52 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/01/05 15:08:52 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/01/05 15:08:53 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
17/01/05 15:08:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where SNAPSHOT_DATE_TIME >= '01-APR-16' and  (1 = 0) 
17/01/05 15:08:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where SNAPSHOT_DATE_TIME >= '01-APR-16' and  (1 = 0) 
17/01/05 15:08:53 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-username/compile/ba4df230b0d18377522bbfe053ed3661/QueryResult.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/01/05 15:08:55 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-username/compile/ba4df230b0d18377522bbfe053ed3661/QueryResult.jar
17/01/05 15:08:55 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import.
17/01/05 15:08:55 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
17/01/05 15:08:55 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
17/01/05 15:08:56 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:username (auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
17/01/05 15:08:56 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
....
```

Comment: Apologies the error message was too long to show all of it, hence pasted part of it.

Comment: *"without the Kerberos Ticket I am unable to login to Putty"* -- yes, but the ticket may have expired at some point, while you are connected... Did you check the output of `klist -e` and `hdfs groups`?

Comment: Samson Scharfrichter, thanks for your response. When i checked the status of the ticket this said 8 hours.. I also restarted the machine, logged into putty and then got another ticket but still no difference..

Comment: Not checked the output of klist mind you so will try this...